# Distinguish NTAG213 from MF0ICU2

Tags: android, tags, nfc, mifare, fingerprinting

Is there any way to distinguish a [NTAG213](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf) from a [MF0ICU2](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF0ICU2.pdf) tag based on its UID, ATQA or SAK values? As I have to program the tags differently (PWD/PACK for NTAG213 or 3DES for MF0ICU2) there must be a way to call either one or another method.

Unfortunately, the Android framework tells me that both tags are `MifareUltralight` with type `TYPE_ULTRALIGHT_C`. The ATQA (`0x0044`) and SAK (`0x00`) are identical, too.

Other apps like [NFC TagInfo by NXP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite) can tell me the exact type of a tag, so I know that there must be some way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you know that the tag is an NXP tag (UID starts with 0x04), you would

1. first send a GET_VERSION command. If this command succeeds, you know that the tag is EV1 or later (MIFARE Ultralight EV1, NTAG21x). Otherwise, you can assume that it is a first generation tag (MIFARE Ultralight, Ultralight C, NTAG203).
2. If the tag is an EV1 tag, you can continue by analyzing the resonse to the GET_VERSION command. This will reveal the product type (NTAG or Ultralight EV1) as well as product subtype, product version and storage size (which allows you to determine the exact chip type:

   ```
   +------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
   | Chip       | Type | Subtype | Version   | Storage size |
   +------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
   | NTAG210    | 0x04 | 0x01    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0B         |
   | NTAG212    | 0x04 | 0x01    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0E         |
   | NTAG213    | 0x04 | 0x02    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0F         |
   | NTAG213F   | 0x04 | 0x04    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0F         |
   | NTAG215    | 0x04 | 0x02    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x11         |
   | NTAG216    | 0x04 | 0x02    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x13         |
   | NTAG216F   | 0x04 | 0x04    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x13         |
   +------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
   | NT3H1101   | 0x04 | 0x02    | 0x01 0x01 | 0x13         |
   | NT3H1101W0 | 0x04 | 0x05    | 0x02 0x01 | 0x13         |
   | NT3H2111W0 | 0x04 | 0x05    | 0x02 0x02 | 0x13         |
   | NT3H2101   | 0x04 | 0x02    | 0x01 0x01 | 0x15         |
   | NT3H1201W0 | 0x04 | 0x05    | 0x02 0x01 | 0x15         |
   | NT3H2211W0 | 0x04 | 0x05    | 0x02 0x02 | 0x15         |
   +------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
   | MF0UL1101  | 0x03 | 0x01    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0B         |
   | MF0ULH1101 | 0x03 | 0x02    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0B         |
   | MF0UL2101  | 0x03 | 0x01    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0E         |
   | MF0ULH2101 | 0x03 | 0x02    | 0x01 0x00 | 0x0E         |
   +------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
   ```
3. If the tag is not an EV1 tag, you can send an AUTHENTICATE (part 1) command. If this command succeeds, you know that the tag is MIFARE Ultralight C. Otherwise, you can assume that the tag is either Ultralight or NTAG203.
4. In order to distinguish between MIFARE Ultralight and NTAG203, you can try to read pages that do not exist on Ultralight (e.g. read page 41).

You can send commands to the tag using the `NfcA` or `MifareUltralight` (if even available for the tag) tag technologies:

```
boolean testCommand(NfcA nfcA, byte[] command) throws IOException {
    final boolean leaveConnected = nfcA.isConnected();

    boolean commandAvailable = false;

    if (!leaveConnected) {
        nfcA.connect();
    }

    try {
        byte[] result = nfcA.transceive(command);
        if ((result != null) &&
            (result.length > 0) &&
            !((result.length == 1) && ((result[0] & 0x00A) == 0x000))) {
            // some response received and response is not a NACK response
            commandAvailable = true;

            // You might also want to check if you received a response
            // that is plausible for the specific command before you
            // assume that the command is actualy available and what
            // you expected...
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // IOException (including TagLostException) could indicate that
        // either the tag is no longer in range or that the command is
        // not supported by the tag 
    }

    try {
        nfcA.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    if (leaveConnected) {
        nfcA.connect();
    }

    return commandAvailable;
}
```

Note that some NFC stacks will generate an `IOException` (typically a `TagLostException`) when a command is not supported by the tag. Regardless of receiving a NACK response or an `IOException` for an unsupported command, you should disconnect and reconnect the tag afterwards in order to reset the state of the tag before you continue to send other commands.

Comment: Unfortunately I always run into an `android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.` when I transmit a command that the NFC tag does not understand. So if I transmit the GET_VERSION command to a MIFARE Ultralight C, I immediately loose the connection and can't send any more commands. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: @Greeny Sure, you can solve this by reconnecting to the tag (`tag.close()` followed by `tag.connect()`) upon getting the exception. In general, it is a good idea to always reconnect after any failure related to Type 2 tags (even after explicitly recieving a NACK response).