# How to get a custom NFC tags in its read?

Tags: android, tags, nfc, mifare, fingerprinting

I'm trying to create an application for smartphones that will copy the NFC tag. I was faced with the problem of inability in some cases to have a label for the tag type.

There is a method:

```
/**
 * Callback when a new tag is discovered by the system.
 * <p>
 * <p>Communication with the card should take place here.
 *
 * @param tag Discovered tag
 */
@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {

    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    MifareClassic mifareClassic = MifareClassic.get(tag);

    if (mifareClassic != null) {
        mAccountCallback.get().onTagsTypeReceived(
            TECH_TYPE_MFR_CLASS, mifareClassic.getType());
        mAccountCallback.get().onMifareClassicReceived(mifareClassic);
    }
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);

    if (nfcA != null) {
        mAccountCallback.get().onNfcAReceived(nfcA);
    }
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
}
```

For the tag, which contains the list of MifareUltralight MifareClassic technology or access type of label is through the method:

```
.getType()
```

But if these technologies are not available, this method becomes unavailable. However, by reading the same labels you use the PC-connected reader b programs Arduino 1.8.5 their data is read without problems:

[A screenshot of the monitor output from programs Arduino 1.8.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WML17.png)

What to do to be able to type any labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an arbitrary NFC tag task yet failed to solve. The solution is found only for NFC type A. the Document company ["NXP Semiconductors" AN10833 "MIFARE Type Identification Procedure"](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10833.pdf) in section 3.2 Coding of Select Acknowledge (SAK) defines the corresponding values of SAK different types of tags. On the basis of this code has appeared:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        String type = "";
        int mSak = (int) (sak & 0x7F);

        if (mTagType.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.tag_type))) {
            switch (mSak) {
                case 0x04:
                    type = getString(R.string.sak_indicates_uid_is_not_complete);
                    break;
                case 0x09:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_classic_protocol_320_bytes);
                    break;
                case 0x08:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_classic_protocol_1kb);
                    break;
                case 0x18:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_classic_protocol_4kb);
                    break;
                case 0x00:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_ultralight_or_ultralight_c);
                    break;
                case 0x10:
                case 0x11:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_plus);
                    break;
                case 0x01:
                    type = getString(R.string.only_mentioned_in_nxp_an_10833_mifare_type_identification_procedure);
                    break;
                case 0x20:
                    type = getString(R.string.picc_compliant_with_iso_iec_14443_4);
                    break;
                case 0x40:
                    type = getString(R.string.picc_compliant_with_iso_iec_18092_nfc);
                    break;
                default:
                    type = getString(R.string.picc_type_unknown);
                    break;
                }
                mTagType.setText(type);
            }
        }
    });
```

To get the value SAK is the method of the class android.nfc.tech.NfcA:

```
.getSak()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your tags seem to be MIFARE Ultralight tags, you could get similar type information (i.e. the `getType()` method) from the `MifareUltralight` tag technology object:

```
MifareUltralight mifareUltralight = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
if (mifareUltralight != null) {
    ... = mifareUltralight.getType();
}
```

It's questionable though how useful that kind of type information may be. See these question for better approaches towards fingerprinting different types of MIFARE Ultralight / NTAG products:

- [Distinguish different types of MIFARE Ultralight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45545493/2425802)
- [Distinguish NTAG213 from MF0ICU2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37002498/2425802)

However, also note that fingerprinting arbitrarary types of tags is certainly not a trivial task (also see [How to detect manufacturer from NFC tag using Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233652/2425802)).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will give it a try

Comment: I rewrote the code so:

    NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);   
    if (nfcA != null) {
        int counter = 0;    
        while (!nfcA.isConnected()) {
            try {
                nfcA.connect();    
                byte[] command = new byte[] {(byte) 0x60};    
                ByteArrayOutputStream output 
                    = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
                byte[] recvBuffer  = nfcA.transceive(command);
                ...

And here I have always thrown exception: android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost. How to avoid it?

Comment: @NonameNoferstname A `TagLostException` in this situation indicates that the tag does not support the GET_VERSION command. You should close and re-open the connection in that case to continue.

Comment: can you share the link to the document that lists all the commands for NfcA tags

Comment: @NonameNoferstname There is no single document for arbitrary NfcA tags. The command sets vary between the various tag platforms.

Comment: OK, let's make some documents. Or maybe there are ready algorithms for reading NfcA tags of any type?

Comment: Here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819027/nfca-transceive-commands-documentation-nfc-a-iso-14443-3a] I found a link to this document: [http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf]. But I have not found descriptions of the signatures of the teams. Where can I find them?